# remove default padding on jetpack compose textfield

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to customize `TextField` composable in Jetpack Compose. I am trying to achieve the result in the image below, but somehow `TextField` has some **default paddings** which i couldn't find how to change values of. I want to remove default paddings and customize it

(The image on the right one is the result i achieved. I drew a border so that you can see it has padding, btw below that `TextField` are just `Text` composables, they aren't `TextFields`)

[image]
[image]

Below is my `TextField` code

```
TextField(
    value = "",
    onValueChange = {},
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1F)
        .padding(0.dp)
        .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Red),
    placeholder = {
        Text(
            "5555 5555 5555 5555", style = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Gray
            )
        )
    },
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `BasicTextField`, it's a plain text field without any decorations. Note that it doesn't have placeholder/hint too, you have to implement those by yourself if you need.

```
BasicTextField(value = "", onValueChange = {}, Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
```

Since [**1.2.0-alpha04**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.2.0-alpha04) it's much easier to make your `BasicTextField` look like `TextField` or `OutlinedTextField`. You can copy source code of `TextField`, which is pretty short since most of logic was moved into `TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox`, and pass the needed padding value into `contentPadding` parameter of `TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox`.

Comment: What if you need to add a `trailingIcon` to your `BasicTextField`?

Comment: @kc_dev Pass it a `TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox` which has `leadingIcon` and `trailingIcon` parameters as `decorationBox` parameter

Comment: Copying source code is bad practice.  If this is the only solution, then there isn't a solution.

Answer (score 39):

In the latest alpha release ([androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.2.0-alpha04)) they exposed [`TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/TextFieldDefaults#TextFieldDecorationBox(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.InteractionSource,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues)).

This is the implementation of the `decorationBox` composable used in the material `TextField` implementation.

You can use it as follows:

```kotlin
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    modifier = modifier,
    visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    enabled = enabled,
    singleLine = singleLine,
) { innerTextField ->
    TextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
        value = value,
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
        innerTextField = innerTextField,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        enabled = enabled,
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp), // this is how you can remove the padding
    )
}
```

This will allow you to remove the padding but still get the rest of the features that come with `TextField`.

Remember to use the same `MutableInteractionSource` for both the `BasicTextField` and the `TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox`.

The official documentation I linked to above shows more examples if its usage.

Comment: it's now deprecated

Comment: not sure what you mean by "it", but neither the `BasicTextField` composable function nor the `TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox` composable function are deprecated as of the latest stable release (1.4.3) nor the latest alpha release (1.5.0-alpha04).

the `BasicTextField` composable function was updated to include a `minLines` parameter, and the original `BasicTextField` function was deprecated to encourage use of the new function but not removed for binary compatibility reasons.

the above code is completely compatible with the new function signature.

Answer (score 14):

Thank you all, i did use BasicTextField and achieved the result i wanted :)

```
@Composable
fun BottomOutlineTextField(placeholder: String, value: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit) {

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color(0xFF969EBD) else Color.Gray
        ),
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                if (value.isEmpty()) {
                    Text(
                        text = placeholder,
                        color = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) Color(0xFF969EBD) else Color.Gray,
                        fontSize = 14.sp
                    )
                }
            }
            innerTextField()
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Congratulations

Comment: Then shouldn't you mark Phillip's answer as the correct answer?

Comment: This solution is very good, but another problem shows up, the Focus bottom indicator doesn't appear.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to cut off the 16.dp at the start. I managed to this in the following way:

```
BoxWithConstraints(modifier = Modifier
          .clipToBounds()
) {
    TextField(modifier = Modifier
        .requiredWidth(maxWidth+16.dp)
        .offset(x=(-8).dp))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by coping all source code from TextField and replace this lines of code :

```
              val paddingToIcon = TextFieldPadding - HorizontalIconPadding
//            val padding = Modifier.padding(
//                start = if (leading != null) paddingToIcon else TextFieldPadding,
//                end = if (trailing != null) paddingToIcon else TextFieldPadding
//            )
            val padding = Modifier.padding(
                start = if (leading != null) paddingToIcon else 0.dp,
                end = if (trailing != null) paddingToIcon else 0.dp
            )
```

And this work great!

Comment: Do you even know what is actually asked?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
...
decorationBox{
     TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
          ....
     )
```

required me to add the anotation **@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)** which seems to not be a good aproach for a release scenario.
Instead, I could get the result I as expecteing by the following implementation:

```
@Composable
fun Input(
    text: TextFieldValue = TextFieldValue(),
    onValueChanged: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit = { },
    keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
    imeAction: ImeAction = ImeAction.Done,
    isEnable: Boolean = true,
    singleLine: Boolean = true,
    shape: Shape = rounded,
    autoCorrect: Boolean = false,
    innerPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(15.dp, 7.dp)
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val fontSize = 16.sp

    BasicTextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = onValueChanged,
        Modifier
            .clip(shape)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray, shape)
            .background(Color.White),
        textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = fontSize),
        enabled = isEnable,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            KeyboardCapitalization.None,
            autoCorrect,
            keyboardType,
            imeAction
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onAny = {
                focusManager.clearFocus()
            }
        ),
        decorationBox = {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
            ) {

                if(text.text.isBlank()) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Search",
                        style = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = fontSize)
                    )
                }
                it()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score -1):

You can put your TextField in a Box and apply modifiers, e.g.

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier.background(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 10),
            color = colorBackgroundGray
        )
    ) {
        TextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(8.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)...
}
```

Comment: Good solution for just adding padding - in case you don't need the underline and adopt the colors accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

The default `TextOverflow` value in `Text` composables is `TextOverflow.Clip`

If your text is well centered, but some of the top or bottom is clipped you can update with the following exemple :

```
placeholder = {
        Text(
            "5555 5555 5555 5555", style = TextStyle(
                color = Color.Gray
            ), overflow = TextOverflow.Visible
        )
    }
```

Visual representation example:

[image: Visual representation example]

Comment: The placeholder text doesn't get aligned vertically. I'm using it with `SearchBar`

Answer (score -4):

Actually that is innate, it follows material guidelines. If you wish to disable it, an alternative could be to set the height of the TextField explicitly, and matching it with the font size of the text. That way it will only extend till the text does. Another way would be to look at the source of TextField. You could just copy the source and make modifications to meet your requirements. The former sounds like an easy fix, however, the latter is no big deal as well. It is doable, and is a recommended practice to customize behavior for your needs. Also, just as a side note, I don't think it is a good idea to disable that padding. It was added to design guidelines since it seems pretty sensible and natural to have it. Sometimes we find some designs attractive when we think about them but they aren't as good when seen implemented.

Comment: doesn't work...