# Adjust TextField label Padding in Compose with decorationBox

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to adjust the start padding of the label in my `TextSearchBar` composable.

I understand that one option is to use a `BasicTextField` composable but i want to avoid this and use `contentPadding` parameter via `decorationBox` added in `androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04` (mentioned by jeran in below post).

I am having difficulties in adding decorationBox (not too familiar on how lambda parameter function works). Please help how i can implement decorationBox to adjust the start padding of the label text?

[remove default padding on jetpack compose textfield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600128/remove-default-padding-on-jetpack-compose-textfield).

```
@Composable
fun TextSearchBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    value: String,
    label: String,
    onDoneActionClick: () -> Unit = {},
    onClearClick: () -> Unit = {},
    onFocusChanged: (FocusState) -> Unit = {},
    onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = { query ->
            onValueChanged(query)
        },
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 4.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .onFocusChanged { onFocusChanged(it) },
        textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
        label = { Text(text = label) },
        trailingIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = { onClearClick() }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Clear, contentDescription = "Clear")
            }
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { onDoneActionClick() }),
        singleLine = true,
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(textColor = Color.Gray,
            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
            disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        //decorationBox = {???}
    )
}
```

Comment: You seems to misunderstood the answer. `decorationBox` wasn't added to `TextField`, the answer you're referring to shows how to implement the view which will work just like `TextField` but using `BasicTextField`, meaning that you can customize `decorationBox`.

Comment: is there a real world example of how to implement this? the answer provided only a snippet and not a front to back example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `BasicTextField` instead of the `TextField`.

Use the **`contentPadding`** attribute to change the paddings:

```
val colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors()

BasicTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    textStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .background(
            color = colors.backgroundColor(enabled).value,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
        ),
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    enabled = enabled,
    singleLine = singleLine
) {
    TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
        value =text,
        innerTextField = it,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        enabled = enabled,
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        label = { Text(text = "label") },
        trailingIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {  }) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Clear, contentDescription = "Clear")
            }
        },
        placeholder = { /* ... */ },
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        // change the start padding
        contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
            start = 4.dp
        )
    )
}
```

[image]

Comment: where does the `interactionSource` come from oder how to initialize is? Thanks

Comment: @MarkDelphi yes you need to initialize it before the `BasicTextField` declaration starts. 

like this --> val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }