# Jetpack Compose - Show trailingIcon in BasicTextField?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-compose-textfield

`TextField` has way too much padding by default for the screen I'm building, so I'm forced to use `BasicTextField` (see: [this post on default TextField padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600128/remove-default-padding-on-jetpack-compose-textfield))

The problem is, `BasicTextField` doesn't take in a `trailingIcon` parameter. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Do you want to add a leadingIcon/trailingIcon while you are still using a `BasicTextField` or do you want to use a `TextField`/`OutlinedTextField` and be able to set all the paddings? Also do you need the solution for Compose version `1.1.x` or is `> 1.2.0-beta` also okay (because DecorationBox defaults have been exposed in one of the 1.2.0 alpha versions it allows for better solutions)? One way to get around this would be using Compose version `1.2.0-beta`+ and manually exposing the `contentPadding` parameter(s) for `TextField` and/or `OutlinedTextField`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with 1.2.0 you can use the `TextFieldDecorationBox` with the `BasicTextField`. Here you can use the `trailingIcon` and `contentPadding` attributes:

```
BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,        
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    enabled = enabled,
    singleLine = singleLine
) {
    TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox(
        value = value,
        innerTextField = it,
        singleLine = singleLine,
        enabled = enabled,
        visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
        trailingIcon = { /* ... */ },
        interactionSource = interactionSource,
        contentPadding = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldWithoutLabelPadding(
               //...top = 0.dp, bottom = 0.dp
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: `TextFieldDefaults.TextFieldDecorationBox` is deprecated when using `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"` or `"androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"`. The replacement is `TextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox`.

Comment: If your `BasicTextField` is using a `decorationBox = { innerTextField -> ... }`, then you have to use the `innerTextField` property like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68600128/remove-default-padding-on-jetpack-compose-textfield#71305641