# Jetpack Compose TextField cuts text on scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `TextField` with a fixed height. When the user enters a longer text it will scroll. It will cut off any text within the padding when scrolling:

[image]

Basically something like this:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { value -> text = value },
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp),
    colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        backgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    )
)
```

It is possible to adjust/remove the padding for a `TextField`, by using `BasicTextField` directly, e.g. see [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68600128/1350902).

However I want to keep the padding, but without the clipping of the text when the user scrolls. A simple `Text` Composable has this behavior.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. The text is not cut, it is just the scrolling behaviour.

Comment: Compare the Scrolling behavior to the one from a simple `Text`:
- `Text` will let you scroll to the edge of the Composable (including padding)
- `TextField` will always show the padding even when scrolled

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `onTextLayout`, as it provides you both with information about the `TextField`'s overflow flags and current number of lines:

```
    onTextLayout = { result ->
        fieldLineCount = result.lineCount
        if(result.didOverflowWidth) {
            // effectively the same thing as setting the maxLines
            fieldLineCount = fieldLineCount.plus(1).coerceAtMost(maxNumberOfLines)
        }
    }
```

Now, if I understand your case correctly, you want to have both fixed height and dynamic height based on the number of lines.

We can achieve that by setting the height based on the variable mentioned above `fieldLineCount` as following:

```
        TextField(modifier = Modifier.height(
            with(LocalDensity.current) {
                LocalTheme.styles.category.fontSize
                    .toDp()
                    // or any other logic you want to limit the size by
                    .plus(2.dp)
                    .times(fieldLineCount)
            },...
        ))
```

Note, that `LocalDensity.current` provides us the ability to parse `.sp` values to `.dp` values.
Also, I personally use the custom `BasicTextField` you mentioned, and it pays off, as I can use these kinds of workarounds.

So If you have a problem with the native component, I recommend posting an issue to Google's issuetracker.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `BasicTextField` and modify its `decorationBox` parameter.
Simply put `innerTextField()` inside a scrollable `Column` and add `Spacer`s at the top and the bottom of it.

```
var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Hello Stackoverflow")
    }
    val paddingSize = remember { 16.dp }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(100.dp),
        value = text,
        onValueChange = { text = it },
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(paddingSize))
                innerTextField()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(paddingSize))
            }

        }
    )
```

Comment: Using a column gives other weird behaviors. For example if you open the keyboard it won't scroll properly to the cursor position.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `maxLines` parameter of the `TextField` to avoid clipping. Set it to 1 or 2, per your case, then adjust the height/font-size so the max lines you specify are accomodated correctly. It will likely start to snap to the visible portion, cutting the extra stuff entirely.

Comment: Well I want to allow larger texts and I want a scrollable `TextField`

Comment: The solution I proposed, will limit the number of lines shown on the screen. It won't disallow addition of more lines. `maxLines` number of lines will be displayed at a time, no matter the total number of lines present. At least try the solution before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: I did not mean to be rude at all. I tried your solution and it results in the same clipping.

Comment: I was way out of line, I didn't actually run the stuff on my own. I just assumed you didn't. I'll post something if I find a solution.

Comment: Mind posting the code piece used to generate that text in the image? Thanks.

Comment: I've added some sample code to my question. Note that this behavior doesn't happen in a scrollable `Text`.